# Translate jQuery code in plain JavaScript for Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I need to translate this jQuery code into javascript for use in Google Tag Manager, but I'm having some trouble with the translation:

```
$('.book-wrapper').click(function() {return( $('.book-title', this).text() )});
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**document.querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to grab all the elements with the `book-wrapper` class:

```
var wrappers= document.querySelectorAll('.book-wrapper');
```

Iterate through the collection, adding click handlers.  Use [**this.querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to grab the title of the clicked `book-wrapper`:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < wrappers.length ; i++) {
  wrappers[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var title= this.querySelector('.book-title').textContent;
    console.log(title);
    return title;
  });
}
```

```js
var wrappers= document.querySelectorAll('.book-wrapper');

for(var i = 0 ; i < wrappers.length ; i++) {
  wrappers[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var title= this.querySelector('.book-title').textContent;
    console.log(title);
    return title;
  });
}
```

```css
.book-wrapper {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-wrapper">
  <div class="book-title">The Little Prince</div>
  <div>
    This is the story about a little prince.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="book-wrapper">
  <div class="book-title">The Little Mermaid</div>
  <div>
    This is the story about a little mermaid.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like something along these lines, I think:

```js
    var els = document.querySelector('.book-wrapper');

    for (var ix = 0; ix < els.length; ix++) {
      els[ix].addEventListener('click', getText);
    }

    function getText(e) {
      var titles = e.target.querySelector('.book-title');
      return titles[0].innerText || null;
    }
```

```html
<div class="book-wrapper">
  <div class="book-title">A Tale of Two Cities</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think Paul's answer is more accurate. Your example looks for ALL .book-title classes, not just the ones under .book-wrapper elements.

Comment: Actually, OP's code does look under the `.book-wrapper` elements, due to the `this` parameter here:  `$('.book-title', this)`

Comment: I think you want to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below should work for you

```html
<div class="book-wrapper">Click here to see name of the book</div>
<div class="book-title">Lord of the Rings</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

  var bookWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('book-wrapper');

  for (var x = 0; x < bookWrapper.length; x++) {
     bookWrapper[x].addEventListener('click', getText);
  }

  function getText() {
    alert(document.getElementsByClassName('book-title')[0].innerHTML);
    return document.getElementsByClassName('book-title')[0].innerHTML;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: OP is using `this` as the context (`$('.book-title', this)`), which implies that `book-title` is a child of `book-wrapper`.